How to prevent user from going to upper directory by vsftpd, in Ubuntu
The directories and the access setting is like below.
/home/directoroy1
rwxr-xr-x 4 user1 user1 4096

/home
rwxrwxr-x 5 root root 4096

And in vsftpd.conf, I set like below.
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

And then restart vsftpd as below.
systemctl restart vsftpd

However whenever I test with Filezilla with the ID user1,
firstly it goes to it's designated directory /home/directory1,
but I can still see .. and able to click it to see upper directory. I can even go see every other directory including root directory, with user1. Where did I do wrong?

It turns out that my problem was SFTP. When using SFTP, vsftpd.conf setting does not work, and user can go up tp upper directory. So I did the followings:
(1) Change /etc/ssh/sshd_config
--> Add the following:
 Match User user1 
  ChrootDirectory /home/directory1
  ForceCommand internal-sftp 
  AllowTcpForwarding no

(2) Set the directories as below:
/home
rwxr-xr-x root root

/home/directory1
rwxr-xr-x root root

(3) Add one more directory under /home/user1
/home/directory1/data
rwx------ user1 user1

Then user1's home directory was set as /home/directory1
and user1 could not go to upper directory as I wished. And user1 was able to upload files on /home/directory1/data.
